# Are there any free, premade penetration testing labs?

Tags: network, penetration-test, vlans

I've already assembled a lab consisting of Kali, Metasploitable, and a Windows XP machine, but are they're any premade lab solutions available that offer up a bit more complexity or even predesignated goals? I am aware of different services that will allow you to VPN into a network, but is there a free/cheap alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the best solution I have used is [Core Impact](http://www.coresecurity.com/core-impact-pro), but it doesn't come cheap. Of course there is always [BackTrack](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/), which includes most of the tools you'll need and is completely free.

However, I would say that in almost all cases a one stop solution will not fit all situations and its best to have a wide and varied tool set.

I would suggest always having a good intercepting proxy, like OWASP [ZAP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project) or [WebScarab](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_WebScarab_Project).

In some cases you'll also find that these tools are just not good enough and you have to create your own tool to exploit a vulnerability.

Comment: I think he is looking for a vulnerable network where he can try out different tools and exploits.

Comment: You are correct, @mohrphium.

Comment: Ah, well check out webgoat from OWASP and also the HACME range of VMs from McAfee.